# How can i allow to only uploading 10MB max and only .gif jpg and png

Tags: php

i need to only allow 10MB max upload and only .gif .png .jpg, how can i do?
It is for uploading images, creates a new directory and upload the image but i need the 10 MB limit and for sure, only this formats.

```
<?php 

$dirname = uniqid();
mkdir("uploads/$dirname", 0777);

$myfile = fopen("uploads/$dirname/index.php", "w") or die("");
$txt = "<?php
header('Location: /publictools');
?>";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "<?php
header('Location: /publictools');
?>";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);


$target_path = "uploads/$dirname/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{ 
echo "<div align='center'><span style='color:green;'>Listo, Encontraras tu archivo en: http://********/uploads/$dirname/". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], $target_path). "</span></div><br>";
}else{
echo "<div align='center'>Ha ocurrido un error!</div>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For filesize, simply check against the `size` of the uploaded file:

```
if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] > 10485760) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
}
```

The size here is specified in **bytes**, so 10 megabytes would be `10485760`.

For file format, you have to check against the `name` of the uploaded file, and then check the extension with **[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)** and `PATHINFO_EXTENSION`:

```
$target_file = basename($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
}
```

The above explicitly only allows `PNG`, `GIF` and `JPG` (or `JPEG`) files, but you can make use of an array to store the desired file types if you want.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: it works 50/50 it says the message that it is not the extension to use but it upload the file?

Comment: Yes, because you also need to **prevent** the file upload if those conditionals are met. I'd recommend setting a flag that sets the upload is valid by default, then in the conditionals that state the upload is now invalid. Finally, only upload the file if the flag is still valid.